# Preseed file whith ufw command do not work

Tags: 14.04, ufw, preseed

In Trusty the command `ufw ufw/enable boolean true` works very well, but the `ufw ufw/allow_known_ports multiselect SSH` do not work. Why?

Comment: How it doesn't work? `echo "
ufw ufw/allow_known_ports multiselect SSH" | sudo debconf-set-selections` works for me.

Comment: Can I view your preseed cfg file?

Comment: I don't have preseed file.

Comment: In my case I install Ubuntu in unattended way... This command works on a preseed.cfg file for 12.04 but not for 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Old mainline kernel 3.14.1 (12.04) was retained after upgrade as it was newer than what 14.04 had.

Both UFW & Firestarter seemed to work but did nothing even when I tried to block everything.

Solution: 
- Installed 3.15.RC2 kkernel.
- Removed 3.14.1 kernel.
- Downloaded & installed 3.14.1 again (as 3.15.2.RC2 was unstable on my machine).
- Removed 3.15.RC2 kernel.

Now firewall rules are working fine.

Think this mess happened as kernel was retained from older OS & that messed somethings up.

Hope this resolves the issue for you as it did for me.

Comment: Thank you Gurvender, but I am trying to install a fresh vanilla installation.